# Right click on layer in TOCControl get a context menu

Tags: arcgis-engine

Is there a way to right click on a layer in the AxTOCControl and get a context menu?

I would like the options to be something like: {annotate layer, change annotation, move layer up or down the view stack}

Using ArcEngine 10 C# VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the sample: [Displaying a TOCControl context menu](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/0001000000s5000000.htm)?