# Programmatically reordering ArcGIS layers

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, shapefile

I programmatically create several layers for my map and I want my layers to be on top of the layers from the original map.

Is there a way I can do that? I also want to be able to put "bring forward/backward" as a menu item in the TOC context menu.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What language are you programming with (ArcObjects, Python)?

Comment: Sorry, ArcEngine 10 .Net 4.

Comment: See. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/how-to-let-user-only-rearrange-layers-in-a-group-layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
mapControl.MoveLayerTo(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Your question is similar to this one:

[Right click on layer in TOCControl get a context menu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/right-click-on-layer-in-toccontrol-get-a-context-menu)

Comment: Yes, thanks, i have seen that TOCControl link before, but i also implemented it, but i still couldn't figure out how to move layer up down, thanks.

Comment: @Kev84, your question has multiple parts, TOC context menus, and TOC context menu items, and move map layer up and down.  What parts do you still need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Is this for one of the web frameworks or desktop?

Comment: I suspect the downvote occurred because although this is a good question, it should have been entered as a comment below the original question, rather than a reply.  @Artwork provides a good example you can follow.

Comment: However, it's hard to comment when you don't have that privilege.

Comment: @Anthony There's [a reason](http://stats.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for that restriction :-).  I guess it's to encourage people to earn reputation first.